Flask Application: cannot import name 'Bootstrap5' from 'flask_bootstrap'
I'm encountering an error in my Flask application. I'm trying to use Bootstrap5 with Bootstrap-Flask, but I keep getting the following error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'Bootstrap5' from 'flask_bootstrap' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_bootstrap/__init__.py)

Details:

I'm using a virtual environment with Python 3.12.
pip freeze confirms Bootstrap-Flask==2.4.0 is installed within the virtual environment.
I don't have flask-bootstrap installed to not mess up with bootstrap-flask.
My app.py file is using the following import statement:

from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap5

app = Flask(__name__)
bootstrap = Bootstrap5(app)

Does anyone know what is preventing flask_bootstrap from importing bootstrap5?
I have already read a similar post here but none of the answers posted there solved the issue: cannot import name 'Bootstrap5' from 'flask_bootstrap'?

For clarity please edit your question and add from flask import Flask to your app.py.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

documentation of bootstrap-flask shows that there are two modules with similar names flask-bootstrap and bootstrap-flask - and maybe you installed wrong module.

or maybe you created file flask_bootstrap.py or folder flask_bootstrap and now Python tries to import from your file flask_bootstrap.py instead of module flask_bootstrap

error shows you full path to source code - so you could open this code to see what you really have in module. Maybe you will have to delete this module manually and install it again.

you say you use Python 3.12 but error shows path wih ../python3.10/.. - so maybe you installed correct module in 3.12 but you run code with 3.10 which has wrong version. Maybe install module using python3.10 -m pip install ... to have it in 3.10, or maybe you forgot to activavet venv with 3.12
